# tmhdynamiclocaleprovider.localelocationpattern 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

-I add the js file to my html:

```
'public/lib/angular-dynamic-locale/tmhDynamicLocale.min.js',
```

-I add the module to my dependencies:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies =
        ['pascalprecht.translate',
         'tmh.dynamicLocale'
        ];
```

Also, I override the default path to the stored Angular i18n locale files in my project:

```
angular.module('core', ['tmh.dynamicLocale'])
    .config(function(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
        tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('public/lib/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
    });
```

Finally, I inject tmhDynamicLocale to my controller and set the desired locale:

```
angular.module('core').controller('tmhDynamicLocale',
    function(tmhDynamicLocale) {
   $scope.spanish = function () {

            tmhDynamicLocale.set('es');

}
```

When I run the app, I have this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/lib/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Any help?

Comment: What happens if you load the URL shown in the error in a browser tab directly? does it load the JS? sounds like a path or file loading error

Comment: /public/lib/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es.js is not a valid path. However, I think that the path is correct in my project

Comment: Sounds like you need to get that file into the path the server is loading files from but would need more details about what server you're running and how that's configured, ultimately need to get the file loading though or else trying to use a module or whatever defined in it isn't going to work out.  Appears the module expects you to have loaded the i18n locale files separately from the module itself https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/README.md